# The revision number could use some more room

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list

There's (too) little space between the revision number on the left, and the edit summary and links to the right, when the revision number has three digits. See for example [the most often edited Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4673436/revisions):

[image]

and once that number reaches 1000, it will overflow (in Firefox) or underflow (in Safari).

Comment: Feature request: once a post reaches revision 999, automatically lock. /s

Comment: While this is an issue which should be addressed, as there are likely a notable number of posts with >= 100 revisions, it's not all that likely for that particular post to encounter the overflow at 999 revisions issue, given that it was last edited in 2016.

Comment: @Makyen true. If I'd place my bets on the first post to reach 1k revisions, it would be on [the Sandbox here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/revisions).